# Why does Haskell have Data.Sequence?

Tags: haskell

Why does Haskell have Data.Sequence? Aren't (lazy) lists already the most general forward iterators possible (by virtue of being free monoids)?

Comment: They're more efficient for many operations, such as concatenation, especially on the right.

Comment: Another operation worth mentioning is [`index`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html#v:index), which gets an `i`-th element in _O(log(min(i,n-i)))_ time. For lists, the complexity is _O(i)_.

Answer (score 14):

The details are mentioned on the first paragraph on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html). As pointed by @AndrewC they offer many operations efficiently example concatenating two sequences, viewing the right end of a sequence or adding elements at the end of a sequence.